# Template 10 AutoSuggestBox in PageHeader

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, template10

I'm currently developing a UWP app and I'm using the the Template10 Hamburger template. I wanted to add an AutoSuggestBox in the PageHeader which works fine if I don't set any primary or secondary commands. If I do set any commands, both commands and AutoSuggestBox overlap. What I've done was set a padding right value for the PageHeader like so:

```
<controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" Text="Main Page" Padding="0,0,283,0">
    <!--  place stretched, across top  -->
    <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
    <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
    <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
    <!--  secondary commands  -->
    <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoSettings}" Label="Settings" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
    </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
</controls:PageHeader>
<AutoSuggestBox Margin="0,8,12,0" Width="270" QueryIcon="Find" PlaceholderText="Search">
    <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

My question is this the suggested way of doing this or is there another way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I think the most straightforward way to put content in a CommandBar (and thus in a PageHeader, that inherits from it) is to use CommandBar Content property, like this:

```
    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" BackButtonVisibility="Visible" Frame="{x:Bind Frame}">
        <controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="Shuffle" Icon="Shuffle"></AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Label="Send" Icon="Send"></AppBarButton>
        </controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>
        <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
        <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
        <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
        <controls:PageHeader.Content>
            <AutoSuggestBox Margin="0,8,12,0" Width="270" QueryIcon="Find" PlaceholderText="Search">
            </AutoSuggestBox>
        </controls:PageHeader.Content>
    </controls:PageHeader>
</RelativePanel>
```

Unfortunatly, the Content area of the CommandBar in fixed on the left side of the screen, and honestly I don't know an easy way to switch it on the right.
There is a **FlowDirection property**, but it's intended to use for right-to-left languages, a can cause some very odd behaviors if used in left-to-right languages (first thing you can notice i f you try it is that the search icon of the AutoSuggestBox switch on the left of the box, and that a back button, if present, switch at the far right of the bar, which I think users will find quite strange).

However, you can achieve what you want by putting two PageHeader one on the side of the other, leveraging the advanced positioning capabilities of the RelativePanel: in the first one you put primary and (eventually) secondary commands; in the second your AutoSuggestBox and eventually other content if you need it. Be aware, you must give a width (or a MaxWidth) to the first PageHeader (the one on the left that contains the commands) that match the content you are going to put in it. Also, you have to change its HorizontalAlignment to *Left*, and remove RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel.
In the second PageHeader you use RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel = True, RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel = true, and RelativePanel.RightOf = pageHeader (that is, the name you give to the first PageHeader), like in the following code:

```
    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" BackButtonVisibility="Visible" Frame="{x:Bind Frame}" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>
            <!--Two sample primary commands -->
            <AppBarButton Label="Shuffle" Icon="Shuffle"></AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Label="Send" Icon="Send"></AppBarButton>
        </controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>

        <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
        <!--<RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>-->
        <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
    </controls:PageHeader>
    <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <controls:PageHeader.Content>
            <AutoSuggestBox Margin="0,8,12,0" Width="270" QueryIcon="Find" PlaceholderText="Search">
            </AutoSuggestBox>
        </controls:PageHeader.Content>

        <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
        <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
        <RelativePanel.RightOf>pageHeader</RelativePanel.RightOf>
    </controls:PageHeader>
</RelativePanel>
```

The result is the one you can see in the following screenshot:

[Two PageHeader side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG07I.png)

Hope it has helped.

Answer (score 1):

Hey what I did for the AutoSuggestBox what to put it in a UserControl and called that usercontrol in the Content of the AppBarButton as follow:

```
 <AppBarButton x:Name="SearchBarUserControl"
                          Style="{StaticResource SearchAppBarButtonStyle}"
                          Visibility="Visible">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <controls1:SearchBarUserControl Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
 </AppBarButton>
```

Edit1:

your code should look like this:

```
<controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" Text="Main Page" Padding="0,0,283,0">
  <AppBarButton x:Name="SearchBarUserControl"
                              Style="{StaticResource SearchAppBarButtonStyle}"
                              Visibility="Visible">
                    <AppBarButton.Content>
                        <controls1:SearchBarUserControl Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </AppBarButton.Content>
     </AppBarButton>
    <!--  place stretched, across top  -->
    <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
    <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
    <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
    <!--  secondary commands  -->
    <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoSettings}" Label="Settings" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
    </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
</controls:PageHeader>
```

Edit 2:  (search bar in secondary commandbar)

```
<controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" Text="Main Page" Padding="0,0,283,0">
    <!--  place stretched, across top  -->
    <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
    <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
    <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
    <!--  secondary commands  -->
    <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoSettings}" Label="Settings" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
        <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
<AppBarButton x:Name="SearchBarUserControl"
                              Style="{StaticResource SearchAppBarButtonStyle}"
                              Visibility="Visible">
                    <AppBarButton.Content>
                        <controls1:SearchBarUserControl Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </AppBarButton.Content>
     </AppBarButton>

  </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
</controls:PageHeader>
```

Comment: I would insert this in Shell.xaml file?

Comment: in your <controls:PageHeader>

Comment: When doing so, it puts the search bar to the left of everything. What I want  is to have it to right of the secondary commands.

Comment: I updated the code please tell me if this works for you

Comment: When applying the the updated code, the search box is moved into the secondary command menu, which is not what I wanted. Also, for some reason the search bar isn't visible in the menu, just only a blank space when you hover it. There has to be a better way implement a search to be place to right in the pageHeader...